# How do I add a secondary layer to a concave model

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have a low-poly model of a purple crystal and I want to add a thin transparent layer on-top of it, I've tried:

- Fattening a copy of the model.
- Scaling a copy of the model.
- Extruding along normals.
- Extruding along vertex normals.

But all of them end with the second mesh intersecting the first. If you know something that could work please tell me!

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of it? Maybe it's not necessary to use another mesh and solution could be in Cycles nodes.

Comment: Im exporting to a pretty light weight game engine so I don't think it would be able to replicate that

Comment: have you tried extruding but not moving the extrusion and then scaling?  For most of my models that has worked for me, if I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the external surface of the model (that will be the internal surface of your transparent layer) add a Solidify modifier to it, set the solidify "offset" property properly (should be 1 or -1) and the proper thickness you want it to have.